# How do I reference a text box to use to fill out the rest of the userform from entered data, almost like a search bar

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to make a userform that can bring up data using an ID number.

I am trying to reference a text box and select it, and then using it as a reference to fill out the Time and comments in the sheet. I think the is I cant put "txtID" into the Find function.

Here is an example of my code:

```
Sheet1.Select
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.Find(What:="txtID", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
ActiveCell.Select

ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8).Value = txtTime2
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 9).Value = txtComment2
```

Comment: you need to qualify your sheets and stop using the macro recorder to learn... you should NEVER use `select` or `activate` as they are unreliable - 

beside here, what websites are you trying to learn from?

Comment: I took a class years ago in college, and just here and www.onlinepclearning.com, the rest I am just kinda improvising as best as I can. Matlab is really where I am a more experienced, not an expert by any means, but in matlab I can put together a good code.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that Selection.Find(What:="txtID") searches for the word txtID in column A, but I think you want to search for the data in a textbox named txtID on a form.  Please try the following.  Change UserForm1 to the name of your form if it's different.

```
Dim ID
ID = UserForm1.Controls("txtID").Value

Sheet1.Select
Columns("A:A").Select

Selection.Find(What:=ID, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
ActiveCell.Select

ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8).Value = "=txtTime2"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 9).Value = "=txtComment2"
```

The form needs to be loaded and already contain the data in txtID.  Is your code in the userform or another module?

The second problem is that you need to store formulas in the offset cells that refer to the data in the cells named txtTime2 and txtComment2.  The code below should do what you want.

```
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8).Value = "=txtTime2"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 9).Value = "=txtComment2"
```

Comment: The Column A is the only column that the ID numbers are at, so I assumed that it would make sense to only search that column.       And, txtID is the name of a texbox in a userform that I want the userform to automatically find and fill out the coresponding data in column 8 and 9. also thank you for the helping!